# How to index confidence intervals (2.5% and 97.5%) in an adipart/oecosimu object?

Tags: r, vegan

I'm running additive diversity partitioning models using the adipart() function in the vegan package in r. From the resulting adipart object, I would like to index the 2.5% and 97.5% columns as vectors so I can use them in another dataframe. I can in index everything else in the result, but for some reason these values are not referenced in any of the function or package descriptions, including in oecosimu(), where resulting adipart values are described in detail. I've included an example below using built-in mite data which produce an adipart object the same as the one I get using my data (modified from https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/blob/master/man/adipart.Rd) .

I have tried indexing all possible resulting values of ADP.mite using "$" and [[]]. None are applicable to the 2.5% and 97.5% confidence intervals.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
data(mite)
data(mite.xy)
data(mite.env)
#Function to get equal area partitions of the mite data
cutter <- function (x, cut = seq(0, 10, by = 2.5)) {
out <- rep(1, length(x))
for (i in 2:(length(cut) - 1))
out[which(x > cut[i] & x <= cut[(i + 1)])] <- i
return(out)}
#The hierarchy of sample aggregation
levsm <- with(mite.xy, data.frame(
l1=1:nrow(mite),
l2=cutter(y, cut = seq(0, 10, by = 2.5)),
l3=cutter(y, cut = seq(0, 10, by = 5)),
l4=rep(1, nrow(mite))))

ADP.mite<-adipart(mite, levsm, index="richness", nsimul=19)
```

Answer (score 1):

The quantiles are not returned, but you must calculate them yourself from the simulated values:

```r
apply(ADP.mite$oecosimu$simulated, 1, quantile, probs=c(0.025, 0.975))
```

Alternatively you can grab simulated values with `permustats` and extract quantiles from its summary:

```r
ps <- permustats(ADP.mite)
summary(ps)$quantile # also returns the median
```